# How can I create a search bar in a map chart using Vega-lite?

Tags: javascript, vega-lite, vega

I am using an example of the Vega-lite's site, [this](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/airport_connections.html) one and I want to create a search bar, like [this](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/param_search_input.html) one. My charts appears as it should, but the search bar doesn't work.

This is my code. The search bar should have appeared, just like in the second example. What I am missing? I have declared in the `params` object my `search_input`. I've added the condition, just like the second example. But an error pops: Unrecognized signal name: "search_input".

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "An interactive visualization of connections among major U.S. airports in 2008. Based on a U.S. airports example by Mike Bostock.",
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "geoshape",
        "fill": "#ddd",
        "stroke": "#fff",
        "strokeWidth": 1
      },
      "data": {
        "url": "data/us-10m.json",
        "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "states"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "rule", "color": "#000", "opacity": 0.35},
      "data": {"url": "data/flights-airport.csv"},
      "transform": [
        {"filter": {"param": "org", "empty": false}},
        {
          "lookup": "origin",
          "from": {
            "data": {"url": "data/airports.csv"},
            "key": "iata",
            "fields": ["latitude", "longitude"]
          }
        },
        {
          "lookup": "destination",
          "from": {
            "data": {"url": "data/airports.csv"},
            "key": "iata",
            "fields": ["latitude", "longitude"]
          },
          "as": ["lat2", "lon2"]
        }
      ],
      "encoding": {
        "latitude": {"field": "latitude"},
        "longitude": {"field": "longitude"},
        "latitude2": {"field": "lat2"},
        "longitude2": {"field": "lon2"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "circle"},
      "data": {"url": "data/flights-airport.csv"},
      "transform": [
        {"aggregate": [{"op": "count", "as": "routes"}], "groupby": ["origin"]},
        {
          "lookup": "origin",
          "from": {
            "data": {"url": "data/airports.csv"},
            "key": "iata",
            "fields": ["state", "latitude", "longitude"]
          }
        },
        {"filter": "datum.state !== 'PR' && datum.state !== 'VI'"}
      ],
      "params": [
        {
         "name": "org",
         "select": {
          "type": "point",
          "on": "pointerover",
          "nearest": true,
          "fields": ["origin"]
         }
       },
       {
        "name": "search_input",
        "bind": {
          "input": "search", 
          "placeholder": "Search Airport", 
          "name": "Search"
         },
         "value": ""
       }

      ],
      "encoding": {
        "latitude": {"field": "latitude"},
        "longitude": {"field": "longitude"},
        "size": {
          "field": "routes",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "scale": {"rangeMax": 1000},
          "legend": null
        },
        "order": {
          "field": "routes",
          "sort": "descending"
        },
        "opacity": { 
           "condition": {
              "test": "test(regexp(search_input,'i'),datum.origin)",
              "value": 0.8
           },
           "value": 0.1
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "projection": {"type": "albersUsa"},
  "width": 900,
  "height": 500
}
```

Comment: Still haven't found a solution to this.

Comment: Please format your code so it works in vega.github.io/editor. Then I will take a look-see.

Comment: @APBReports I have edited my code so that it will work in vega.github.io/editor. Please consider that this code will pop an error, the error that I am describing in my post. The problematic piece of the code is the second object in ```params```, where I add my search_input.

Comment: Hi Christopher, Did you test my solution? Please mark as solved it worked fine.

Comment: @APBReports Hello, Happy New Year! Sorry for the great delay. Yes, the solution works 100% as I wanted. The change was that you created another ```params``` outside of the layer?

Comment: @APBReports Can you clarify why you moved the params outside of the layer? Shouldn't we have the appropriate params inside the layer that uses it?

Comment: Hi. Check out issue 7812 I think its related.
https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/7812

"only selection parameters can be nested within views. Variable parameters can only be defined at the top-level."

Comment: @APBReports Aah, that is informative, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "An interactive visualization of connections among major U.S. airports in 2008. Based on a U.S. airports example by Mike Bostock.",
  "params": [
    {
      "name": "search_input",
      "bind": {
        "input": "search",
        "placeholder": "Search Airport",
        "name": "Search"
      },
      "value": ""
    }
  ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "geoshape",
        "fill": "#ddd",
        "stroke": "#fff",
        "strokeWidth": 1
      },
      "data": {
        "url": "data/us-10m.json",
        "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "states"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "rule", "color": "#000", "opacity": 0.35},
      "data": {"url": "data/flights-airport.csv"},
      "transform": [
        {"filter": {"param": "org", "empty": false}},
        {
          "lookup": "origin",
          "from": {
            "data": {"url": "data/airports.csv"},
            "key": "iata",
            "fields": ["latitude", "longitude"]
          }
        },
        {
          "lookup": "destination",
          "from": {
            "data": {"url": "data/airports.csv"},
            "key": "iata",
            "fields": ["latitude", "longitude"]
          },
          "as": ["lat2", "lon2"]
        }
      ],
      "encoding": {
        "latitude": {"field": "latitude"},
        "longitude": {"field": "longitude"},
        "latitude2": {"field": "lat2"},
        "longitude2": {"field": "lon2"}
      }
    },
    {
      "params": [
        {
          "name": "org",
          "select": {
            "type": "point",
            "on": "pointerover",
            "nearest": true,
            "fields": ["origin"]
          }
        }
      ],
      "mark": {"type": "circle"},
      "data": {"url": "data/flights-airport.csv"},
      "transform": [
        {"aggregate": [{"op": "count", "as": "routes"}], "groupby": ["origin"]},
        {
          "lookup": "origin",
          "from": {
            "data": {"url": "data/airports.csv"},
            "key": "iata",
            "fields": ["state", "latitude", "longitude"]
          }
        },
        {"filter": "datum.state !== 'PR' && datum.state !== 'VI'"}
      ],
      "encoding": {
        "latitude": {"field": "latitude"},
        "longitude": {"field": "longitude"},
        "size": {
          "field": "routes",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "scale": {"rangeMax": 1000},
          "legend": null
        },
        "order": {"field": "routes", "sort": "descending"},
        "opacity": {
          "condition": {
            "test": "test(regexp(search_input,'i'),datum.origin)",
            "value": 0.8
          },
          "value": 0.1
        },
        "tooltip": [{"field": "origin", "title": "Airport", "type": "nominal"}]
      }
    }
  ],
  "projection": {"type": "albersUsa"},
  "width": 900,
  "height": 500
}
```